# Get Wordpress Core Functions in external PHP script

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I try to get wordpress Core functions in an external PHP Script
I have an own AJAX-PHP file. To make queries, i included wp load at the beginning of my code ( `require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );`).

This file gets loaded on different sites of my page and the query depends on the site, the script is loaded. The query does work, but i can't get WP information like the page id of the site, the script is loaded. Is there any way to get those wp-information(for example width global $post)?

Comment: I'm confused -- why would you expect there to be current page ID when you're loading WP Core from outside of WordPress? You're basically just loading all of the functions that WP contains, not actually accessing a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this at the top of your script, this Loads the WordPress environment and template.

```
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```